# Prediction for classification yields wrong result scikit learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I have generated model out of a dataset, and tried to find the best algorithm based on cohen_kappa score and prediction accuracy. I run it against various algorithms since the kind of data that I will get is not known, so finding best algorithm by comparing their kappa and accuracy.
My data is cross validated with 10 folds.

I did comparison among Random Forest, Decision Tree, SGDClassifier, Perceptron, Passive Aggressive, Logistic Regression, Gradient Boosting, Naive Bayes, KNeighbors.

For my example, I got Random Forest as the best algorithm for Classification with Kappa=1 and accuracy=0.94

My classification was a 2 class classification with condition like ResponseTime > 200.

Now when I try to run prediction, for some dependent variable values, I get correct prediction but for some it is totally wrong.

I tried all different algorithms but the prediction results are very inconsistent.

Thanks

Comment: Can you upload your data ?

Comment: One of the sample data I have is attached. But this one has kappa=0 for Random Forest with accuracy of 0.97.

Comment: Sorry hit enter before finishing my response. One of the sample data I have is attached. But this one has kappa=0 for Random Forest with accuracy of 0.97. Attaching sample data file that I used to generate model. I am trying to regenerate dataset where kappa value was 1. With this dataset, I get correct value for prediction for one dataset input but wrong prediction for different input. Attaching all the 3 arff files.

Comment: Having issues with uploading a file and sharing..give me some time

Answer (score 0):

You have to look closely to wrong prediction's feature values. May be you have contradictory data in your dataset. For example, if you have observations and labels like this, you will never ever get 100% accuracy no matter how hard you have tried, how you cross-validated or stacked your algorithms. 75% accuracy is the top score here.

```
0 => 0
0 => 0
0 => 0
0 => 1 <- this sample have wrong label
1 => 1
1 => 1
1 => 1
1 => 0 <- this sample have wrong label
```